# How to force calibration before measuring a DWG file in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

After checking the documentation of Forge Viewer, I found that there is an option to force the calibration before taking measurements in PDF sheets.

But is there a similar option to force calibration on other types of files, like DWG? Or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean the `forcePDFCalibration` option mentioned [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/TypeDefs/Settings/).

For **DWG** one option could be setting `forceCalibrate` to `true` after loading the model:

```
var ext = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Measure");
ext.forceCalibrate = true;
```